# dotnet ef cannot find any compatible framework version

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I have executed

```
>dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold connectionString EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

It generated files but with warning about freshest version is available.

I installed the latest one

```
>dotnet tool install -g dotnet-ef
```

Then again:

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold connectionString EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.2' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.0.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.1.15 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.2.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.0-preview3.19553.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.2' was not found.

How to run the dotnet ef or how I can rollback to the previous version?

Comment: Getting exactly same error after installing .NET Core 3.1